# Oracle 11g Express Edition - missing or invalid schema authorization identifier

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-11g

I have a new fresh instance of Oracle Express 11g.
I'm trying to create a new Schema with a Table and a View in the default db (xe).

My script is:

```
create user XAuthority identified by mysecret;

alter session set current_schema = XAuthority;

create schema authorization XAuthority
create table CUSTOMER (  ID int, CUSTOMER text)
create view CUSTOMER_VIEW as select * from CUSTOMER
grant select on CUSTOMER_VIEW to xareadonly;
```

but I get an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-02421: missing or invalid schema authorization identifier
>   02421. 00000 -  "missing or invalid schema authorization identifier"
>
> *Cause:    the schema name is missing or is incorrect in an authorization
>              clause of a create schema statement.
>
> *Action:   If the name is present, it must be the same as the current
>              schema.

I'm familiar with Postgres and MySql but it seems Oracle is quite different.  Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### CREATE SCHEMA
>
> #### Purpose
>
> Use the CREATE SCHEMA statement to create multiple tables and views and perform multiple grants in your own schema in a single transaction.

Well you have multiple issues. First of all you need to have `CREATE SESSION` system privilege granted to the newly created user. Secondly your data types are incompatible in Oracle(`int` should be converted to `number` and `text` to `varchar2`).

In order to use `CREATE SCHEMA` statement you need to be connected to database as the user which you have specified on the statement.

The problem is you are not connected to database as `xauthority` by altering the session.

```
SQL> conn sys/password
Connected.

SQL> create user XAuthority identified by mysecret;

User created.

SQL> alter session set current_schema = XAuthority;

Session altered.

SQL> create schema authorization XAuthority
create table CUSTOMER(ID number, CUSTOMER_name varchar2(20))
create view CUSTOMER_VIEW as select * from CUSTOMER
grant select on CUSTOMER_VIEW to xareadonly;  2    3    4  
create schema authorization XAuthority
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02421: missing or invalid schema authorization identifier

SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
```

The user should be `xauthority` but it is still `SYS`.

You need `create session` system privilege to connect to the database.

```
SQL> grant create session to xauthority;

Grant succeeded.
```

You need quota on tablespace to create schema objects such as table.

```
SQL> alter user xauthority quota unlimited on orapdb1_tbs1;

User altered.

SQL> conn xauthority/mysecret
Connected.

SQL> conn xauthority/mysecret
Connected.
SQL> create schema authorization XAuthority
create table CUSTOMER(ID number, CUSTOMER_name varchar2(20))
create view CUSTOMER_VIEW as select * from CUSTOMER;

Schema created.
```

Comment: thanks you, but just one thing.  What is `orapdb1_tbs1`, or what should it be in my case?

Comment: @Francis: I that is my tablespace name on which I have assigned the quota to the newly created user. In your case it might be different like `USERS` or other.